# Redux state and momentjs

Tags: redux, react-redux, momentjs

I have several dates in my redux state.

Within my app, I want to manipulate only [moment](https://momentjs.com/) objects.

To achieve this, I added a function that takes my AJAX queries, and *momentize* all of my dates.

But when I check what I get in the store, I still have a string (`"2018-07-10T08:31:09.877Z"`) which appears to be the `JSON.stringify` version of my moment object.

How am I supposed to handle this? I am aware I can have `listeners` on the store, but, this won't add a processing when deserializing the state into an object.

I am surprised I haven't found anything on the web, besides [this issue](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/82), which is even more specific since it deals with persisting the store.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redux documentation highly recommends to only put plain serializable objects in the Store.

Because of this, I'm approaching the same case as yours as having a *Selector layer*, where I'm getting the needed Store data in the proper format and later use the formatted (computed) data in the components.

So here's the flow I can recommend you:

1. Keep your Store's Dates in UNIX timestamps.
2. Have a *Selector layer*, where you will access the Store and convert the UNIX timestamps to Moment objects. You can play with [reselect library](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect/).
3. In your components you will get the Store's objects, as calling the selectors.

[Can I put functions, promises, or other non-serializable items in my store state?](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#organizing-state-non-serializable)

> It is highly recommended that you only put plain serializable objects,
>   arrays, and primitives into your store. It's technically possible to
>   insert non-serializable items into the store, but doing so can break
>   the ability to persist and rehydrate the contents of a store, as well
>   as interfere with time-travel debugging.
>
> If you are okay with things like persistence and time-travel debugging
>   potentially not working as intended, then you are totally welcome to
>   put non-serializable items into your Redux store. Ultimately, it's
>   your application, and how you implement it is up to you. As with many
>   other things about Redux, just be sure you understand what tradeoffs
>   are involved.

Comment: Yeah, I came up with the reselect solution as well. I guess there is not much choice then. But I'm still unclear on whether redux does the serialization of stores without a word. If it does, it would make sense to have access to some deserialized function as well, wouldn't it?

Comment: I mean, how can I make sure objects are serialized at first?

Comment: First of all `redux` library itself does *not* serialize the object's automatically, because of the performance reasons. It's on your own. According to your use case, I guess you're using a library or middleware that do it for you. For example `redux-persist` library does automatic serialization - when the state object gets persisted, it first gets serialized with JSON.stringify().

Comment: It is indeed best to serialize your moment objects on the store. I just ran into issues with hydrating the store when server-side-rendering (SSR) using Next.js, because I didn't serialize my moment objects...

Answer (score 2):

For the future readers, I ended up changing my mind completely: using a selector works, but I also had data that came from form inputs in some other part of the store, and those did not make sense to handle with `reselect`.

Hence I decided to store the dates in ISO string format (`"2018-07-10T08:31:09.877Z"`) and to `moment`ize them as late as possible (Eg. `<DatePicker type='date' value={moment(this.props.value)} />`).

This is less elegant, probably a little less performant, but I have more control.

If someone comes up with a better solution, I'd be happy to read it!